# Wait For HTML Content to Measure First Contentful Paint

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, paint

I am interested in designing a test page that will generate HTML pages with images (of different sizes, quantity, and extensions). I know that the content of a page can be set by using a custom HTML string in [Puppeter's setContent](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/581#issuecomment-325441872). However, I would like to gather First Contentful Paint from this newly generated page. The algorithm would look something like the following:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

  page.goto('file://path/to/empty.html');

  await navigationPromise;

  page.setContent(`[ Custom HTML String ]`);

  // I would like to measure this after the HTML changes
  const firstContentfulPaint = JSON.parse(
    await page.evaluate(() =>
      JSON.stringify(performance.getEntriesByName('first-contentful-paint'))
    )
  );

  console.log(`First paint: ${firstContentfulPaint[0].startTime}`);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say. Maybe it's just me, but what does it mean to "generate HTML pages with images at different types?"

Comment: I may choose to load some (10 to 100) images, which may be svg / png and 60x40 / 16x16 / etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can try budget of LightHouse API, to gather the data related to it,
https://web.dev/use-lighthouse-for-performance-budgets/